# uploading a project from squeak smalltalk to my github account

Tags: github, smalltalk, squeak

id love to know how to upload a project from squeak smalltalk to my github account.
i found very little about it in the web and all i come out with was that i can upload it all to my git and have it as a StringTemplate whice i dont want.

Comment: In Pharo there's a tool called Iceberg that does this. But I'm not sure if it's available in Squeak as well.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on whether you mean a project as in a software project (e. g. one or more packages of Smalltalk code) or as in a Squeak Project (the ones you can open via the Projects menu).

For code, if you use Squeak 5.2 or later, you should try the Git Browser:

[image: How to install and launch the Git Browser]

[image: Screenshot of the Git Browser]

Disclaimer: I am the main developer of that package. The bulk of the Git codebase in Smalltalk has been written by other people though. The project is hosted here: https://github.com/hpi-swa/Squot/ There is also a short introduction there in the README.

To make your project loadable from GitHub into an image, you should also write a [Metacello](https://github.com/Metacello/metacello/) baseline. You should familiarize yourself with Metacello for this if you have not already done so.

---

For Squeak Projects, you can export projects to the file system and then commit those files with the regular Git command line or any tools you prefer. I doubt that it will be very efficient though, since the project files will not be text files.

[image: How to save a Squeak Project to a file]

Comment: "Version Control with Git" also mentions the Git Browser on the Squeak website: https://squeak.org/development/ Pity that you could not find that during your web search.